# Auto phone number detection on dynamic html content

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

As I see, mobile devices (iPhone) can detect phone number format in an HTML, and make it clickable to call that number. But, it does it only static content. If I set a div content dynamically, it does not work, so it does not make the number clickable.

Here a very simple example:

```
<html>
<body>
     <div id="t2">0212 444 0 444</div><br><br>
     <div id="t1"></div>
     <script>
          document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "0212 444 0 444";
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

in this example, even I use same number, first number becomes clickable automatically, but second not. Is there anyway to force a div to check its numbers again after I set its content dynamically?

note: I dont want to set dynamic phone number with  tag. Because, in real application, I dont know the content and what part of it is actually a number.

Comment: To make telephone numbers clickable to call use [`<a href='tel:nnnnnnnnn'`>NNN NN NNNNN</a>`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, I know that, but I need to make it work automatically. Because, even in the example there is only one phone number, I dont know what is the content, and what part of content is phone number

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `href="tel:"`

```html
<html>
<body>
     <div id="t2">0212 444 0 444</div><br><br>
     <div id="t1"></div>
     <script>
          document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "<a href=\"tel:0212 444 0 444\">0212 444 0 444</a>";
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tan, but I need it without using <a> tag